# jsoup bug in Element.empty()

Tags: exception, jsoup

I posted this on the Jsoup group at google.groups, but there doesn't seem to be much activity there lately, so I'll try here as well...

The following code

```
final String html = "<html><head></head><body><div></div></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element body = doc.body();
Element div = body.select("div").first();
body.empty();                   // <--- gives exception at line 56 below
// body.children().remove();    // does not give exception
body.appendChild(div);          // line 56, IndexOutOfBoundsException here
```

with Jsoup 1.6.1, gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException with the following (partial, top 7 lines) stack trace

```
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.removeChild(Node.java:394)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.reparentChild(Node.java:420)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.addChildren(Node.java:402)
at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.appendChild(Element.java:225)
at webfilter.FilterY.<init>(FilterY.java:56)
```

here FilterY is my class containing the code above. If I use body.children().remove() instead of body.empty(), it works fine.

Question is... am I abusing Jsoup here, or is this really a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are using the jSoup library in a wrong way. Lets go line by line:

***You are saving a reference of first child:***

```
Element div = body.select("div").first();
```

***You are removing all of the element's child nodes:***

```
body.empty();
```

***And then you are trying to append the deleted child:***

```
body.appendChild(div);
```

Now the problem is in the last step because when you deleted all the child elements then at that time the parent-child relationship is not broken because `body.empty();` just calls the `clear();` method of the `java.util.List` and it does not break any parent-child linkage, which is not the case when you do `body.children().remove()` and that's why in the following code you are getting the mentioned exception as there are dangling reference to child node:

```
 protected void removeChild(Node out) {
        Validate.isTrue(out.parentNode == this);
        int index = out.siblingIndex();
        childNodes.remove(index); // problem comes here
        reindexChildren();
        out.parentNode = null;
    }
```

**But** if you do something like this then it would work:

```
Element div_child = doc.createElement("div");
body.appendChild(div_child);
```

Comment: In addition, you could also call clone() on div Element